# sfdx - second generation packages - push custom fields fails silently

Tags: custom-field, salesforcedx, push

I have setup three sfdx second gen packages, each with their own sub folder in my umbrella project folder.

Package 1 defines some Custom Objects.

Package 2 adds some custom fields to the custom objects created by Package 1.

Package 3 holds nothing at the moment.

My `sfdx-project.json` lists Package 1 as a dependency for Package 2.

When I do a `sfdx force:source:push` it appears to successfully deploy, but the fields in the org defined by Package 2 are missing. If I change my `sfdx-project.json` file to list only Package 2, without any dependencies, and clear out my `.sfdx/org` subfolder, a `sfdx force:org:push` results in the following errors for my custom fields:

```
N/A           An object 'TP_Transaction__c.TX_VP_BillingEmail__c' of type CustomField was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped direc
tory
```

There a multiple errors as above, for each custom field defined in Package 2. The initial push with the full project configuration also listed the fields from Package 2 as added.

Based on the error above it looks like the sfdx cli is creating a MDAPI `package.xml` correctly listing the custom fields, but not including the old MDAPI CustomObject XML including the fields.

Has anyone else worked around this? Any suggestions for next steps to troubleshoot?

I want to keep our data model fields coupled to the domain that deals with them. This doesn't seem possible currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unlisted known issue with sfdx. I created a git repository to reproduce the issue and reported it to SFDC in a case; https://github.com/JonnyPower/sfdx-push-bug-20190124

I received the following response on my case:

> Our engineers are aware of this and are working to find a solution to fix it.
>
> However we do not have an ETA on the fix yet. Currently the only workaround is what you have already mentioned; performing separate push for the different packages.

I asked for this to be reported as a known issue under Salesforce DX and am awaiting a further response.

Comment: Did you receive any updates from the Salesforce team?

Comment: Ok, this limitation is now described in the following article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321246&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have the same problem.
I would say to use um package by repo, but we are using the same approach as you.
The workaround you can use is:

**Merge all the fields + custom labels in the default package**.

```
    {
        "path": "default",
        "default": true
    },
```

I built a plugin to do it and you can use it.

(https://github.com/dieffrei/sfdx-guidion-plugin/blob/master/src/commands/guidion/build/fix.ts)

Another problem probably you are going to find is about the custom labels, the plugin solve this problem as well.

--- default 
----- labels
----- objects

--- package1
----- labels
----- objects

--- package2
----- labels
----- objects